# Unexpected namespace prefix "xmlns" found for tag LinearLayout (xmlns:tools ERROR)

Tags: java, android, xml-namespaces

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/scroll"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <LinearLayout 
    ***
```

> xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
>   *** This line shows the error Unexpected namespace prefix "xmlns" found for tag LinearLayout, i've tried solutions on stack but didnt get resolved. Please help.

```
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" 
    android:id="@+id/RL">


    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/hello_world"
        android:id="@+id/label1" />


</LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's complaining about the attribute `tools:context=".MainActivity"` that is part of the `<LinearLayout>` tag. It doesn't know what the `tools:` prefix means.

You need to add `xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"` as an attribute to the `<ScrollView>` tag. Alternatively, get rid of the `tools:context` attribute for the `<LinearLayout>` tag.

The `tools:context` (as well as other `tools:...` attributes) are used as part of Android's lint checking of XML files. See [here](http://developer.android.com/tools/debugging/improving-w-lint.html#src) for more info.

Comment: I got rid of the tools:context, I am a beginner programmer so pardon me but wont that cause any conflicts in my program?

Comment: @RidwanWan - For the file you posted, I don't think it makes any difference whether you add the namespace declaration or remove the `tools:context` attribute. That's for this particular file. Speaking generally, removing all `tools:*` attributes means that the Android lint tool will not have as much info to use; consequently it might either generate spurious warnings or fail to generate a warning that would help track down a problem.

Comment: That sounds fair enough, it solved the problem though!
Thank you!